# Selecting files in a sorted list via Applescript in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a bunch of files within a folder that I'd like to periodically delete the oldest 3 files in it. The problem is I can't rely on "creation date" or "last modified date" on these files (long story). These files all have the same name with appended timestamps -- xxxxx 2019-08-29-_01-37.sparsebundle

I've created Automator steps as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/273Nc.jpg).

Now after the "Sort Finder Items" step, how do I use Applescript to select and delete the bottom 2 or 3 files?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move to the **Trash**, or permanently delete, the last three *items* in the `list` returned from the **Sort Finder Items** *action*, add a **Run Apple Script** *action* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    try
        repeat with i in items -3 thru -1 of input
                # To move to Trash, use Finder.
            -- tell application "Finder" to delete alias (i as text)
                # To permanently delete, use System Events.
            -- tell application "System Events" to delete alias (i as text)
        end repeat
    end try
end run
```

Remove the `--` from in front of the `tell application ...` *statement* for which action you wish to take.

If you only want to work with the last two *items* in the `list` then change `-3` to `-2` in: `repeat with i in items -3 thru -1 of input`

Note that this *example* **AppleScript** *code* worked for me in **macOS High Sierra**.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any aditional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thank you! That was extremely helpful. I'd like to add an `if` statement so that it checks the **number** of _items_ in the folder to make sure that there is at least 3 existing files before going into the `try` statement to remove the last 3 _items_, how would I go about it?

Comment: @Europa2010AD, You can use an `if` _statement_ like, e.g., `if not (count input) > n then return` where `n` is the minimum number of backups you want to retain. Place this before the `try` _statement block_. Say you set `n` to `6` and are using `-3` in the `repeat` _statement_, then the backups with never be less then 6 and will not delete until there are 9 or more. Otherwise you'll have to write a more complex `if` _statement_,  or change the `repeat` _statement_, etc.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894! So I tried what you suggested -- I put `if not (count input) > 4 then return` before the `try` _statement block_. Set `n` to `-2 thru -1` in the `repeat` _statement_ in order to remove the last 2 backups. However when I had 5 backups, it'd remove the last 2 backups and I'd be left with 3 backups -- despite my intention to always keep 4.

So I tried to put `if (count input) > 4 then` inside the `repeat` _statement_, and `else exit repeat` after to try and break out of the `repeat` loop once _count input_ equals 4. Doesn't seem to work. Let me post the code separately